# what is the use of resize:detect azure chatbot node js

Tags: javascript, resize, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I would like to know why we have resize:detect option in renderwebchat function for azure chat bot.Can someone explain me  whats the outcome or whats the use of this option.

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    renderMarkdown: markdownIt.render.bind(markdownIt),
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        token: '@ViewData["DirectLineToken"]'
    }),
    user: {
        id: 'test@xx.com,test@xx.com',
        name: 'You',
        OverrideBlockAccess: '@ViewData["OverrideBlockAccess"]',
        LoggedInUserEmail: '@Html.Raw(ViewData["LoggedInUserEmail"])',
        UserEmail: '@Html.Raw(ViewData["UserEmail"])'
    },
    bot: { id: 'HPICEBoTAPP' },
    resize: 'detect',
    userId: '@Html.Raw(ViewData["UserEmail"])',
    styleOptions: styleOptions
}
```

Comment: I want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. Are you saying you're already using this option, and you want to know why you yourself have decided to use it? How can you be using an option without knowing why? How did it get there?

Comment: @KyleDelaney im not using this but i was checking few samples from other applications and across sites to render a bot and one such sample was the above one. Most of the sites had this render option but no where i found out what is the actual purpose

Comment: Why haven't you linked to the samples where you've seen this?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yea,.Sorry for the delay. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/1d6f46282653c0cf8a8cbea30fed4f07164e246e/samples/00.migration/a.v3-to-v4/README.md one such link. Similary i ve seen few other where the samples had the same resize options

Comment: Thank you for the link. I would like to help but I still need some clarification. That sample shows the `resize` property in the object passed to `BotChat.App` and not `WebChat.renderWebChat`. Bot Chat is Web Chat v3, and you're not likely to find much help with it because it's deprecated. Have you seen any samples where the `resize` property is passed to `renderWebChat`? If not, why are you passing it to `renderWebChat` in your question?

Comment: Thanks @KyleDelaney You are right. I kept checking parameters across the sites but i never realised that it was `Botchat.app` and not `renderwebchat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the properties that can be passed to `renderWebChat` here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/API.md

Notice that there is no `user`, `bot`, or `resize` property.